# What else can be done with Rights to Run Sql Profiler

Tags: profiler

when I told my DBA team to give me rights to run Sql profiler in test server they said giving profiler rights means giving admin rights which is against our policy

Can anybody tell me that if a user has Alter trace right to run profiler what else he has access to that is apart from running sql profiler what else he can do  with Alter Trace Rights